# How can I retrieve data stored in a seperate class when calling from ViewController?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am currently learning iOS development using Swift. I am making a simple weather app. I have several buttons to get the weather for the next 4 hours. I am getting the weather from the dark sky API, returned in JSON format. I have finally figured out how to retrieve the correct data from the JSON, and have created a class that fetches the data.

```
typealias WeatherCallback = (Weather) -> Void
typealias ErrorCallback = (Error) -> Void

class NetworkManager {

    class func getWeather(latitude: String, longitude: String, onSuccess: WeatherCallback? = nil, onError: ErrorCallback? = nil) {

        let urlString = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/(api key)/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?units=si"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                onError?(error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    let json  = JSON(data: data!)
                    let weather = Weather()

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        weather.updateWithJSON(dict: json["currently"], hour: 0)

                        for i in 1...4 {
                            weather.updateWithJSON(dict: json["hourly"]["data"][i], hour: i)
                        }
                    }
                    onSuccess?(weather) 
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

And I have a different class to store the retrieved data.

```
class Weather {

    public var currentTime: String = ""
    public var currentTemperature: String = ""

    public var nextHourTime: String = ""
    public var nextHourTemperature: String = ""

    public var nextTwoHourTime: String = ""
    public var nextTwoHourTemperature: String = ""

    public var nextThreeHourTime: String = ""
    public var nextThreeHourTemperature: String = ""

    public var nextFourHourTime: String = ""
    public var nextFourHourTemperature: String = ""

    func updateCurrentData(time: String, temp: String) {
        currentTime = time
        currentTemperature = temp
    }

    func updateWithJSON(dict: JSON, hour: Int){

        switch hour {
        case 0:
            currentTime = dict["time"].stringValue
            currentTemperature = dict["temperature"].stringValue

        case 1:
            nextHourTime = dict["time"].stringValue
            nextHourTemperature = dict["temperature"].stringValue

        case 2:
            nextTwoHourTime = dict["time"].stringValue
            nextTwoHourTemperature = dict["temperature"].stringValue

        case 3:
            nextThreeHourTime = dict["time"].stringValue
            nextThreeHourTemperature = dict["temperature"].stringValue

        case 4:
            nextFourHourTime = dict["time"].stringValue
            nextFourHourTemperature = dict["temperature"].stringValue

        default:
            print("rip")
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem is, I cannot access the stored values in the class `Weather` from within `ViewController`.**

For example

```
let weather = Weather()

print(weather.currentTime)
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: First you should initialize with `Weather` with `updateWithJSON` or `updateCurrentData` method then only by the instance of weather class you can get stored values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating `Weather` class `Singleton`. Using singleton Only one copy of this object exists and the state is shared and reachable by any other object.

```
class Weather {
public static var sharedInstance =  Weather()
...
private init() {
}
}
```

and get object of singleton  like this

```
let weather = Weather.sharedInstance // it will give you the same instance of Weather every time you call it.
```

Comment: Would I then have to assign my variables inside `init`? How would I do that when the variables are assigned inside a function?

Comment: no. we declare init with private to prevent creating other  objects of weather.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate pettern for getting the result in viewcontroller. First Create a Protocol like that:

```
protocol YourDelegateProtocol {
    func getDataFromServer(data: String)
}
```

After that create an instance of this protocol in your NetworkManager class like that:

```
class NetworkManager {
    var delegate: YourDelegateProtocol?    
}
```

After getting the response send the response to your viewcontroller from there:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            onError?(error!)
        } else {
            do {
                let json  = JSON(data: data!)
                  delegate.geDataFromServer(json as String)
                }
                onSuccess?(weather) 
            }
        }
        }.resume()
```

After that get the data in your viewcontroller like that

```
class WeatherData: UIViewController, YourDelegateProtocol {

   var yourModelClass = YourModelClass() //init model class globally.

   func getDataFromServer(data: String) {
    // populate json String into your model class. Then you are ready to go.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create request getWeather in your ViewController. This function gives you access to Weather object as completion handler (WeatherCallback = (Weather) -> Void).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use a Singleton design pattern. Make a Singleton `Weather` class and whenever you get a response from `getWeather` function update your `Weather` singleton class. When you want to user response simply get values from `Weather` class.